# How can I get an arrow to center align with text in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a chart that I'm annotating some text and would like to draw an arrow to a point, however I cannot get the arrow to center align with the text. It always aligns to the left of the text.

I came across this article which shows an arrow tail center aligned with the text and points to the area of concern. This is what I'd like on my chart.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(10,6)

x= np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.01)
y= np.sin(x)

plt.axhline(y=0, color='k',linewidth=1)

# Simple arrow
plt.annotate('Maximum value of sin(x)',xy=(1.55,0.98),xytext=(1,-0.25),
             arrowprops={"width":6,"headwidth":20,'headlength':20},
             horizontalalignment='center',fontsize=15)

plt.plot(x,y,label='sine curve',color='r')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The result is this:

[image]

Where the arrow tail is center aligned with the text. However, when I try to use this snippet of code, mine is aligned to the left of the text. See below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0, 200.25, 0.25)
x2 = x * 1.852

y1 = (np.sqrt(x2**2 + 72227335.111 + (2*x2)*(8498.66667)*(np.sin(0.5*0.0174533))) - 8498.66667) * 3280.84
y15 = (np.sqrt(x2**2 + 72227335.111 + (2*x2)*(8498.66667)*(np.sin(0.025*0.0174533))) - 8498.66667) * 3280.84
y29 = (np.sqrt(x2**2 + 72227335.111 + (2*x2)*(8498.66667)*(np.sin(0.975*0.0174533))) - 8498.66667) * 3280.84

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (14,9))

ax.plot(x,y1,lw = 2, color = 'b')
ax.plot(x,y15, lw = 0.5, color = 'b', alpha = 0.0)
ax.plot(x,y29, lw = 0.5, color = 'b', alpha = 0.0)

ax.set_ylim(ymin = 0)
ax.set_ylim(ymax = 60000)
ax.set_xlim(xmin = 0)
ax.set_xlim(xmax = 200)

ax.fill_between(x, y15,y29,color='b',alpha=.2)

ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='gray')
ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='gray')
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'both', top = False, bottom = False, left = False, right = False, labelsize = 12)

plt.annotate('5045 feet', xy = (50, 1500), xytext = (41.8, 7800), fontsize = 12, fontweight = 'bold', arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '<->', color = 'red', lw = 2))
plt.annotate('10085 feet', xy = (100, 6500), xytext = (90.5, 18000), fontsize = 12, fontweight = 'bold', arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '<->', color = 'red', lw = 2))
plt.annotate('15110 feet', xy = (150, 15000), xytext = (140.5, 31000), fontsize = 12, fontweight = 'bold', arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '<->', color = 'red', lw = 2))
plt.annotate(' 20200 feet', xy = (200, 26500), xytext = (190, 48000), fontsize = 12, fontweight = 'bold', arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '<->', color = 'red', lw = 2))

plt.annotate('Test Text Goes Here',xy=(21,3000),xytext=(33,20000),
             arrowprops={"width":6,"headwidth":20,'headlength':20},
             horizontalalignment='center',fontsize=15)

plt.scatter(20, 1300, s = 200, marker = '*', color = 'purple', zorder = 10)
plt.scatter(98, 11600, s = 200, marker = '*', color = 'purple', zorder = 10)

plt.show()
```

Resulting in something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to get this arrow center-aligned like in the top image?

Comment: Maybe it's because your `xytext`'s (text box coordinate)  x-coordiate is a bit off from `xy`'s (annotate coordinate) x-coordinate? I tried changing `xytext` from `(33,20000)` to `(21,20000)` and the text looks center-aligned with the arrow for me

Comment: So far, all I've figured out is that "center" only works when the word is 17 characters or longer (with `fontsize=15`). I'm trying to dig through the source code to figure out why that is, but I'm not sure if I will find it since I'm not very familiar with the matplotlib source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Set `xycoords='data'` and `xytext=(0, y)`* and both the horizontal & vertical alignment parameters to `"center"` for always text-centered [arrow] annotations

> *Where `y` corresponds to the apparent height¹ of the arrow.

<sub>¹ (In this example, measured in units of `"offset points"` - which will be dependent on the set DPI. [default: 72])</sub>

E.g., the following modification:

```py
labels = [
    "Labels",
    "Composed Of",
    "[Test Text Goes Here]",
    "Varying Lengths Increasingly",
    "Getting Longer With Each Subsequent Label",
][::-1]

# Center-aligned text-arrow annotations
for x, y in zip(range(21, 21 * 11, 21 * 2), range(3000, 3000 * 20, 3000 * 3)):
    plt.annotate(
        labels.pop(),
        xy=(x, y),
        xycoords="data",
        xytext=(0, 140),
        textcoords="offset points",
        arrowprops={"width": 6, "headwidth": 20, "headlength": 20},
        horizontalalignment="center",
        verticalalignment="center",
        fontsize=15,
    )

    plt.scatter(x, y, s=200, marker="*", color="purple", zorder=10)
```

produces:

[image: Matplotlib text-centered arrow annotations]